# How do I handle the error: "No item of this name exists in the PivotTable report."

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, pivot-table, userform

So I have a PivotTable being modified via a commandbox inside of a userform.  If the user types in a name that isn't in the list, I get the error

> No item of this name exists in the PivotTable report.  Rename Name1 to Name2?

where `Name1` is a person on the list and `Name2` is a person not on the list.

I actually get this error like 5 times b/c of the number of PivotTables my commandbox modifies.

I tried the following:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

I was hoping that would simply "skip over" the issue. Nope, that didn't work out haha.

Though ideally I would like to create a custom error message that pops up only one time (instead of 5 times) and tells the user to enter a name from their department/shift. The list (that my commandbox uses) overall has everyone from every shift from every department, but not all people have data in the PivotTable and so just b/c they are on the list my commandbox users, they are not necessarily in the PivotTable. I know that's confusing, but I have to have it that way b/c the same interface is being used by all shifts. I do not have access to the list of people within departments, shifts, etc. I only have a master list of everyone, so that's why my commandbox has to use that.

I'm still "new" to VBA, but I am not new to error handling in general. I know how I would handle this in Java, but not in VBA.

This is the part of code, which fails:

```
Range("D2").Select 
ActiveCell.Value = frmInd_Productivity_TrackerPS.ComboBox1.Value
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Range("F2").Value
```

Update:
I tried adding the following at the very top of my coding, but this just makes the error box pop up even when the person is in the pivottable and the thing works correctly!?! No clue why it's popping up the MessageBox when there is no error!?!

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

ErrHandler:
' error handling code
Resume ErrMessage:

ErrMessage:
MsgBox "Name not found in this Department. Please Enter a New Name from this Department."
Exit Sub
```

Update: It appears as though the box that pops up is an "Alert", not an "Error"???  If I disable all alerts, then it doesn't pop up but I am also not given the opportunity to warn the user that the name they entered is incorrect and it reassigns things automatically (which I don't want!!!).  Any thoughts?  Is there something like an "On Alert GoTo" code I can use?

Comment: [This](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) is a great source to read about VBA error handling best practice. Regarding your case, I think you should find out the solution yourself when you know how err handling works. maybe you could popup a dialog box asking to include an additional name to Pivot (instead of deleting some existant name), or maybe you could create some boolean becoming True only when an error occurs and stating at the end of process "sorry, your name was not in the PivotTable". I think that's up to you how you want to handle it.

Comment: I have been reading that prior to you posting the link but I'm honestly a little lost sir.

I just want it to pop up a box telling the user to enter a name in their department if the name isn't in the pivottable.  I will try some things, but I would appreciate a little directed guidance.  :)

My main problem is that I don't know how to get it to "skip" that error and actually go to the next error?  Can you tell me how to do that? 

In Java, the Try/Catch block automatically goes to the next level after handling the error.  I can't get VBA to just "toss out" the error and continue running.

Comment: Where is your PivotTable located? which cells?

Comment: I have 5 PivotTables in total, all of which get modified by the commandbox.  So each one of them throws up the error, giving me 5 errors in a row that ask me to rename a person on the pivottable to the name of the person that isn't.

B1 is my pivottable filter box.  I have to modify the value from the combobox, which is the value that "F2" winds up as.  In other words, "F2" is my finished product that is "copied" to the pivottable filter box (I know you can't actually "copy" it there, its just setting the value equal to "F2").

Comment: And I should perhaps clarify again that "Resume Next" does not seem to skip the coding.  Perhaps I am placing it in the wrong spot by putting the "On Error Resume Next" as the very first line of code?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to do what I wanted.  I did find a solution though.

Problem solved (band-aid applied):

I made a new sheet that called the info from the combobox.  It converted it and then used it to check whether that info appeared on my pivottable using a loop.  Then I assigned a variable a result based on whether it found it (stored in a new variable).  If the result was 1, an "If" statement executes the entire block of my program.  If the result was 0 (meaning it didn't find the name on the pivottable), then it pops up a message saying to change the name and exits the sub.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `On Error Resume Next` right at the top for Excel to skip your error message.

```vb
Sub FunctionName()

On Error Resume Next
```